# Replacing leading spaces in formatted numbers

Tags: regex, r, format

I would like to replace leading spaces in a string of formatted numbers by a `\phantom{...}` command, where `...` is of the same length as there are leading spaces. What I can do is:

```
x <- c(1, 1., 0.230, 10.1, 1000, 10000.12)
y <- format(round(x, 2), nsmall=2, big.mark="\\\\,", big.interval=3L)
gsub(" ", "\\\\phantom{ }", y)
```

But, I rather would like to have one `\phantom{}` of the appropriate length (such as `\phantom{        }` then several `\phantom{ }`.

**UPDATE**

Based on the solution of Arun, I built this function for formatting numbers in `R` to be aligned in LaTeX tables:

```
tabAlign <- function(x, nsmall=0L, digits=NULL,
                     flag.before="\\\\phantom{", flag.after="}", embrace="$",
                     big.mark="\\\\,", big.interval=3L, ...)
{
    x <- if(!is.null(digits)) round(x, digits=digits) else x
    x <- format(x, nsmall=nsmall, big.mark=big.mark, big.interval=big.interval, ...)
    x <- sub("^([ ]+)", paste0(flag.before, "\\1", flag.after), x) 
    paste0(embrace, x, embrace) 
}
```

Now, let's do something useful with it. `tabAlign(x)` gives:

```
[1] "$\\phantom{       }1.00$" "$\\phantom{       }1.00$"
[3] "$\\phantom{       }0.23$" "$\\phantom{      }10.10$"
[5] "$\\phantom{ }1\\,000.00$" "$10\\,000.12$"
```

Copying-and-pasting this to a LaTeX file reveals that the alignment is not correct. The reason is the `big.mark`. This reserves `nchar(big.mark)=3` spaces (in the `R` character string). However, in LaTeX, this occupies much less space, so that the numbers are not perfectly aligned anymore. Ideally, the `sub()` command thus has to take `nchar(big.mark)` into account (for any given `big.mark`).

**UPDATE 2**

Here is another update, now taking into account hints from DWin.

```
tabAlign <- function(x, nsmall=0L, digits=NULL,
                     flag="\\\\phantom{\\1}", embrace="$",
                     big.mark="\\\\,", big.interval=3L, ...)
{
    ## round (if digits is not NULL)
    x <- if(!is.null(digits)) round(x, digits=digits) else x
    ## determine those with/without big.mark (idea from prettyNum())
    y <- format(x, nsmall=nsmall, trim=TRUE)
    y.sp <- strsplit(y, ".", fixed=TRUE)
    B <- sapply(y.sp, `[`, 1L)
    ind.w.big.mark <- grep(paste0("[0-9]{", big.interval+1L, ",}"), B)
    ind.wo.big.mark <- setdiff(1:length(y), ind.w.big.mark)
    ## format the numbers
    x <- format(x, nsmall=nsmall, big.mark=big.mark, big.interval=big.interval, ...)
    ## substitute spaces
    z <- character(l <- length(x))
    n <- nchar(big.mark)
    for(i in seq_len(l)){
        z[i] <- if(i %in% ind.wo.big.mark) sub("^([ ]+)", paste0(flag, big.mark), x[i])
                else sub("^([ ]+)", flag, x[i])
    }
    ## embrace
    paste0(embrace, z, embrace)
}
```

The only missing piece is to replace not all spaces in `\phantom` in the `if()` part, but only the number of spaces - `n`, where `n <- nchar(big.mark)`. How can this be specified in `sub()`?

**UPDATE 3**

Here is a solution (but not too elegant... see below):

```
tabAlign <- function(x, nsmall=0L, digits=NULL,
                     flag="\\\\phantom{\\1}", embrace="$",
                     big.mark="\\\\,", big.mark2="\\,", big.interval=3L, ...)
{
    ## round (if digits is not NULL)
    x <- if(!is.null(digits)) round(x, digits=digits) else x
    ## determine those with/without big.mark (idea from prettyNum())
    y <- format(x, trim=TRUE)
    y.sp <- strsplit(y, ".", fixed=TRUE)
    B <- sapply(y.sp, `[`, 1L)
    w.big.mark <- grep(paste0("[0-9]{", big.interval+1L, ",}"), B)
    wo.big.mark <- setdiff(1:length(y), w.big.mark)
    ## format the numbers
    x. <- if(length(wo.big.mark) > 0 && length(w.big.mark) > 0) {
        ## format but trim
        y <- format(x, trim=TRUE, nsmall=nsmall, big.mark=big.mark, big.interval=big.interval, ...)
        ## paste big.mark to all numbers without big.mark
        y[wo.big.mark] <- paste0(big.mark2, y[wo.big.mark])
        format(y, justify="right")
    } else { # either all numbers have big.mark or not
        format(x, nsmall=nsmall, big.mark=big.mark, big.interval=big.interval, ...)
    }
    z <- sub("^([ ]+)", flag, x.)
    ## embrace
    paste0(embrace, z, embrace)
}

x <- c(1, 1., 0.230, 10.1, 1000, 10000.12)
tabAlign(x)
tabAlign(x[1:4])
tabAlign(x[5:6])
```

It would be nicer if we could only specify `big.mark` (and not `big.mark2` as well).

Comment: That's why there is the `if()`... For those elements of `x` with a big mark, we substitute all spaces there are. For those elements of `x` with no big mark, there are at least three spaces (due to the fact that there are some elements with big mark and we thus pasted `big.mark` to these strings)

Comment: The code I showed is the best I know at the moment, but it does not do the right thing (neither in R nor in LaTeX). The problem is that for those elements of x without a big mark, the `\phantom{     }` introduces too much space (namely `n` spaces too many, where `n` is the number of characters in `big.mark`).

Comment: I now (Update 3) did it more elegantly. However, it would be great if we could omit the argument `big.mark2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solve the problem? It would be nice to show the desired output (to be sure of the output while testing the expression). Thanks to DWin for his suggestion (see comments).

```
sub("^([ ]+)", "\\\\phantom{\\1}", y)
```

The `(` and `)` captures the matching pattern (which is a bunch of consecutive spaces starting from the beginning of the string) and this captured group can be inserted with `\\1`. If you have more than one parenthesis, then you can insert each captured group with back-referencing from \1 through \9.

Comment: Should put a ```^``` at the beginning of the pattern to ensure it grabs the leading spaces only.  Should probably just do ```sub``` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now as you might expect, the `\phantom{}` commands are for LaTeX. To make this formatting more useful, the phantom command should indeed take into account the space `\\\\,` (a `\,` in LaTeX) reserved by `big.mark`. If you know a solution to that, too, that would be great. In other words, the `sub()` should take `nchar("\\\\,")` (=3) into account.

Comment: I guess the "algorithm" we are looking for is this: If there is no number with `big.mark` then the solution so far is fine. If there is at least one number with `big.mark`, then add (=paste) the `big.mark` in a `phantom{}` to that number (string), too. This is probably the only way we can guarantee that the numbers are correctly aligned afterwards, since we don't know anything about the actual space taken by `big.mark` in LaTeX (the current example with `big.mark=\\\\,` takes a `\,` space in LaTeX -- I'm not even sure if this is half a blank or not in LaTeX)

Comment: I admit that I was quite surprised to see an R expression to be evaluated in replacement argument, but in this case it not needed since, this would give the same results: `sub("^([ ]+)", "\\\\phantom{\\1}", y)`

Comment: Dear Arun, please see the second update. How can I substitute the number of spaces minus `n` (= 3)?